# Согласование по числу

Tags: стилистика, управление

Как правильно написать: "волосы каштанового и пепельного цвета" или "волосы каштанового и пепельного цветов"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласование зависит от ситуации, например:

Сейчас в моде волосы **каштанового и пепельного цвета** (цвет рассматривается отдельно).

Волосы **каштанового и пепельного цветов** могут интересно сочетаться друг с другом (цвета рассматриваются в композиции).

Общее правило согласования

Розенталь: §194. Два определения при одном существительном [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)